# PHP: preg_replace to preg_replace_callback conversion problem

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I'm no PHP expert but I am trying the process of converting `preg_replace()` items with 'e' to `preg_replace_callback()` and found many samples that I though I understood, but apparently don't because it doesn't work.  Here's one with a problem for sure:

Original:

```
$_rowHTML .= @preg_replace("/\[(.+)\]/Uie", "\$_callBackResult['\\1']", $_rowTemplate);
```

My converted version that doesn't work:

```
$_rowHTML .= @preg_replace_callback("/\[(.+)\]/Ui", function($m){ return $_callBackResult[$m[1]];}, $_rowTemplate);
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: `function($m) use ($_callBackResult) { return $_callBackResult[$m[1]];}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was the answer!! thank you!  So what is the rule there, if a variable is used you have to put use in front?   They have others that have `'chr(hexdec("\\1"))'` which I presume would work with the normal conversion of just `return chr(hexdec($m[1]));`

Comment: If you need to access variables inside the anonymous callback, pass them through `use`.

Comment: Prefect!  Whoever closed this doesn't know I read the link several times before even posting a message here and no way I would have ever gotten the answer from it.  The direct answer is is more valuable and clear.